# django-invitation and social registration

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication, django-registration, django-socialauth

Is there any easy way to allow social registration, but only for users that provide an invite code using a system like django-invitation? I was planning on using either django-social-auth or django-allauth. Did anyone try this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably way too late for your needs, but just in case its of use to you or someone else: I have forked django-allauth and added an INVITE_MODE setting so that it can be used along with django-invitation.  Here are the repos:

- https://github.com/lizrice/django-allauth
- https://github.com/lizrice/django-invitation

Comment: Your django-invitation fork 404s - did your pull request get accepted?